# Magento - get number of products in category

Tags: php, magento

I'm listing all of the categories in the sidebar and what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
Category1 (25)
Category2 (3)
Category3 (16)
```

I just need to add the number of products in each category. I've narrowed it down to Navigation.php and I've tried appending `$html .= $this->getProductsCount();` to the `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` function, but nothing happens. I also tried

```
$products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getProductCount();
$html .= $products_count
```

That just breaks it and nothing is displayed. It seems to be the right location, just calling the wrong thing because if I add static content (`$html .= 'some stuff here';`), it works fine. So what is the right way to go about this?

I'm using Magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Magento normally displays product count by default. You could have a look at your theme's category navigation template file which can usually be found at `app/design/frontend/yourTheme/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml`.

To display product count, use something like `echo $_category->getProductCount()` inside the `foreach ($_categories as $_category)` loop.

Comment: I'm using the MageBuzz extension to display the category navigation. How then do I get Magento to use `left.phtml`? I disabled MageBuzz for now. I'm using the default responsive theme.

Comment: Have you cleared magento cache? The default one should have been used if you haved disabled the extension. You can also [turn on template hint](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-) to find out which template file is being used.

Comment: Thank you. It's been a while since I've worked with Magento and that template hint link helped very much. I was able to get it to display now, but to get it to do so, I had to delete the line, `<?php if($_helper->isEnabled()): ?>` located in `catsidebarnav.phtml`. It appears to still be using the `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` function located in `Navigation.php`. I was able to get the count to appear after a little tweaking, but it's displaying outside of the `<li>` element.

Comment: Now I got it to work using the `left.phtml` file. However, the bit of code `echo $_category->getProductCount()` is already there, but is rendering blank. So I added the code I was previously using (via the `getId()`) and it works now.

Comment: This will not work at the store level. It will give product count for products in all stores.